# Can matlab figure have vertical separator line?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to achieve a similar graph to the one shown below. I have been researching how to add lines as separators and put 2 box plots in between 2 lines. The dataset I have is that I have 3 message sizes of type A and 3 same message sizes of type B. I want to draw them side by side based on their sizes. Below is the similar graph that I want to achieve. There are 2 box plots in each column which represent they are the same message size, only different type.

[image: Final result]

What keyword should I search for that result?

Answer (score 3):

What you want can be achieved defining two grouping variables for the data, and using the `'factorseparator'` input of [`boxplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html) to specify which grouping variable should generate separators (vertical lines):

```
X = rand(30, 8); % example data matrix. Each column generates a box
g_sizes = {'16k' '16k' '32k' '32k' '64k' '64k' '128k' '128k'}; % message sizes
g_types = {'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B'}; % messsage types
boxplot(X, {g_sizes g_types}, 'factorseparator', 1) % 1st variable geneates separators
```

[image]

Comment: That is very helpful to me. And one more small thing, Take the first column for example, instead of having 2 "16K", can I merge then into one?

Comment: @NguyenHuy It looks like `boxplot` creates those labels as `text` objects. You could delete them manually (click on one and type `delete(gco)`), and create your own

Comment: okay, I will try that. Thank you very much.